# Chart js. Overflow for the graph container

Tags: chart.js, tooltip, overflow

Can the Chart js tooltips go beyond the boundaries of the graph container (overflow: visible). If so, please give an example or a link to the solution.

I need the tooltip to go beyond the container with the graph.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xv4DE.png)